# Input into child component giving error, but sometime loads

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object that I am passing from a parent component to a child component. When I run `ng serve`, I get an error that the object which was passed cannot be found. However, if I save a file the system will occasionally rerun the build and build correctly and serve the app. The object does indeed work correctly.

I believe that the cause is related to the fact that the data which I am passing comes from a service fetching data. If this is true, what can I do about it?

Parent component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-design-studio',
  templateUrl: './design-studio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./design-studio.component.scss']
})
export class DesignStudioComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  designData: any;

  // Private
  private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any>;

  constructor(private _studio: DesignStudioService) { 
    // Set the defaults
    this.searchInput = new FormControl('');

    // Set the private defaults
    this._unsubscribeAll = new Subject();

    this._studio.onDesignChanged
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
      .subscribe(response => {
          this.designData = response;

          // Prepend and append the cost and menu data
          this.designData.menu.unshift(this.projectMenu);
          this.designData.menu.push(this.costMenu);

          // Add the array to hide/show the side menus
          this.designData.menuShow = [];
          this.designData.menu.forEach((value, index) => {
            this.designData.menuShow[index] =  false;
          });
       });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._studio.onDesignChanged
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
      .subscribe(response => {
          this.designData = response;

          // Prepend and append the cost and menu data
          this.designData.menu.unshift(this.projectMenu);
          this.designData.menu.push(this.costMenu);

        // Add the array to hide/show the side menus
        this.designData.menuShow = [];
        this.designData.menu.forEach((value, index) => {
          this.designData.menuShow[index] =  false;
        });
      });
  }
}
```

Child Component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'design-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  //designData: any;
  @Input() designData: designData;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Error is on the child component: (second `designData` is underlined in error)

```
ERROR in src/app/main/design-studio/sidebar/sidebar.component.ts:12:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'designData'.

    @Input() designData: designData;
```

Comment: Where did you declare/define the `designData` interface/class (the second one that you say is underlined)? I don't see anything in your child component that either declares or imports `designData`. If you change it to `any`, just like you have it in parent component, it should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I believe that I looked at an old example and was not reading it correctly. I relooked at the official docs and that was the mistake that I made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the underlined interface to `any`, just like you have it in the parent component, it should fix your problem.

Also, looking at the code, a couple of points:

- You have duplicate code (maybe because it's WIP) in the constructor and in ngOnInit() - ideally, you would just have everything in `ngOnInit()`.
- You need to unsubscribe from the subscription, usually in `ngOnDestroy()` to avoid memory leaks.